# haskell syntax confusion -- function type declaration

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming

I am trying to learn haskell by going through the learn you a haskell book. I came across a function which confuses me a bit and would like to look for an explanation. This function is rather straightforward. What I don't understand is the first line when declaring the function type. What does ( RealFloat a) =& gt; a -> a -> a do? why are they separated by semicolons?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
cylinder :: ( RealFloat a) =& gt; a -&gt; a -&gt; a
cylinder r h =
    let sideArea = 2 * pi * r * h
        topArea = pi * r ^2
    in sideArea + 2 * topArea
```

Comment: Are the `&gt;` intentional? If not - that is the problem. `&gt;` is the HTML for `>`. The type signature should be `(RealFloat a) => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: oh... you are right, I was reading the pdf version which has retained the html symbols... sorry for my ignorance. Thank you so much

Comment: Fix the HTML syntax with proper `=>` and `->`. Also note that indentation is important, `sideArea` and `topArea` must start on the same column, and the whole function body must be more indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML character entities are denoted `&xxx;` where `xxx` is some valid HTML character code. In specific, `&gt;` is the code for the character `>`, since it means "greater than".

Assuming there is a HTML mistake in the question, the type declaration becomes

```
cylinder :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> a
```

> what does it do?

You read it out like "assuming `a` is an instance of the type class `RealFloat`, `cylinder` takes two values of type `a` and returns a value of type `a`.  You might want to look into the term "currying" to read these declarations.

What it does is to declare the function type.

> why semicolons?

There are no semicolons in the actual type declaration.